# Capturing Graphviz figures in sphinx-gallery

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sphinx, graphviz

I'm generating examples with [`sphinx-gallery`](https://sphinx-gallery.github.io/stable/index.html), and would like to embed [`graphviz`](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) outputs automatically, similar to how `matplotlib` figures are captured.

A screenshot of my current progress is below. Notice the captured `Out` shows string or byte representations of the figures.

I would like the `Out` to be an image/svg.

---

[image: Current result for embedding graphviz outputs in sphinx-gallery. The outputs are xml or raw byte sequences rather than image data.]

---

I've investigated the following:

- `graphviz` can [export SVG for Jupyter notebooks through a private `_repr_svg_()` method](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#jupyter-notebooks), but `sphinx-gallery` interprets this as a string.
- `sphinx-gallery` has [experimental support for "Custom Image Scrapers"](https://sphinx-gallery.github.io/stable/advanced.html#write-a-custom-image-scraper), but I want to avoid glue code in my examples where I "*write image files, then read them back into generated html.*"
- How does `graphviz` documentation accomplish this? [By generating .png figures ahead of time and embedding them with `.. image::` directives](https://github.com/xflr6/graphviz/blob/885220d49eee1f04cd6493cc69acd72684c59e05/docs/manual.rst).

---

**Update** (2020-11-26): Adding a `_repr_html_` that wraps the graphviz's `_repr_svg_` method seems like the shortest route. I implemented a rough version:

[image: An alternate version of graphviz was used to generate this image. Here the graph is plotted automatically, rather than a string being printed.]

---

Here is the code for what I have tried already:

```py
# File: examples/plot_graphviz_svg.py

"""
==================================================
Capturing the output of Graphviz in Sphinx-Gallery
==================================================

This is a quick demo trying to capture the SVG output
from Graphviz and embed it in a Sphinx Gallery.
"""

import graphviz

dig = graphviz.Digraph('G', filename='hello.gv')
dig.edge('hello', 'world')
dig._repr_svg_()

# %%
# The first output should be above, the next should appear below:

dig2 = graphviz.Digraph('G2', filename="hello2.gv")
dig2.edge('world', 'hello')
dig.pipe()
```

A minimal `sphinx` `conf.py`:

```py
project = 'sphinx-graphviz-svg'
copyright = '2020, Alexander L. Hayes'
author = 'Alexander L. Hayes'
release = '0.0.1'
extensions = [
    'sphinx_gallery.gen_gallery',
]
templates_path = ['_templates']
exclude_patterns = []
html_theme = 'alabaster'
html_static_path = ['_static']
```

And a minimal `index.rst` linking to an Example Gallery:

```
Welcome to sphinx-graphviz-svg's documentation!
===============================================

.. toctree::
   :hidden:
   :maxdepth: 1
   :caption: Example Gallery

   auto_examples/index
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an open pull request in the [`graphviz`](https://github.com/xflr6/graphviz/) repository here: [#121](https://github.com/xflr6/graphviz/pull/121).

If you're impatient, here is one possibility with a fairly small wrapper:

```py
class PlotGraphviz:

    def __init__(self, dot_string):
        self.dot_string = dot_string

    def _repr_html_(self):
        return graphviz.Source(self.dot_string)._repr_svg_()
```

This will be cleaner assuming the pull request is merged in the future.

For now:

```py
# File: examples/plot_graphviz_svg.py

"""
==================================================
Capturing the output of Graphviz in Sphinx-Gallery
==================================================

This is a quick demo trying to capture the SVG output
from Graphviz and embed it in a Sphinx Gallery.
"""

import graphviz

class PlotGraphviz:

    def __init__(self, dot_string):
        self.dot_string = dot_string

    def _repr_html_(self):
        return graphviz.Source(self.dot_string)._repr_svg_()

# %%
# First example:

dig = graphviz.Digraph()
dig.edge("hello", "world")
PlotGraphviz(str(dig))

# %%
# More info ...
```

**Renders into**:

---

[image: Image showing the result that solved the problem.]